# How to access a global variable which is hidden by a macro definition?

Tags: c, macros

Is it possible to access a variable at global scope which has been used in a (self-referential) macro?
I'm using the term used to refer to such macros.
See [gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html)
My sample code is based on the example code shown there.

Simple Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo = 10; /*A variable at global scope. There may be a few of these.*/

#define foo (4 + foo) /*A self-referential macro. There may be a few of these.*/

int main()
{
    printf("foo = %d\n", foo); /*Prints 14. The value after the macro expansion */  

    /*Is there any way to access the global variable *foo* here?*/  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `printf` accesses `foo`—it reads the value of `foo`, which is an access. Do you mean to ask whether it is possible to set the value? Or to read the value without going through the macro?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: The foo value in printf is that of the macro, not the global variable.

Comment: Also, the macro is not self-referential. When the identifier of a macro appears inside the replacement text, it is not replaced, so it is not a reference to the macro.

Comment: The value used in the `printf` comes from the result of expanding the macro and evaluating the resulting expression. That expression contains `foo`, which causes an access of `foo`.

Comment: I'm using the term used to refer to such macros. See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html

Comment: Simply remove the macro `#define` from the code entirely. Obfuscated code like this need to be rewritten.

Comment: The question is lacking motivation (and context), and shows insufficient research.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `#undef foo` to remove the macro definition.

Comment: Yes, doing this after the printf allows the global variable to be accessed again.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to access a variable at global scope which has been used in a self-referential macro?

**No, it is not.** FWIW, redefining a global variable as a [self-referential](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html) macro is very ugly and poor taste and makes unreadable code. Don't do that.

Read more about the various [translation phases](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/translation_phases) in C (later, refer also to the C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)). [Preprocessing](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/preprocessor) happens (conceptually) before actual parsing.

In practice, don't `#define foo`, but e.g. `#define FOO_MAC` and use `FOO_MAC` or `foo` appropriately (as [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51941746/841108) by Eric Postpischil, you might instead use `#undef`, but that makes the code less readable).

BTW, you can get the preprocessed form (as a text file). With [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), [invoke it](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html) as

```
gcc -Wall -C -E yourfoocode.c > yourfoocode.i
```

then look with a pager or editor inside file `yourfoocode.i`

Read also [documentation of cpp](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/index.html).

With GCC specifically, you might also use [asm labels](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Asm-Labels.html) (e.g. `int otherfoo asm ("foo");`) in global variable declarations to declare another variable sitting at the same location. But that will confuse the reader and could upset the compiler optimization passes (e.g. `&foo != &otherfoo` might be optimized to true but is false), so you don't want to do that.

Be aware that C programming requires a lot of good conventions and styles to have readable code, so in practice what you ask should *never* happen. When it does, you need to rewrite your code (just for readability reasons).

Comment: Most coding guides require that macros be named with capital snake_case, so `#define FOO` or `#define FOO_MAC` would be better

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and practical suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The code is a burden on readability and maintainability.
I hope you are only asking this because it is some legacy code you have to cope with and I feel with you.

The closest you can get to accessing the global variable, with the least change to the shown code and not adding another code file, I imagine would be

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo = 10; /*A variable at global scope. There may be a few of these.*/
int* backdoorfoo = &foo;

#define foo (4 + foo) /*A self-referential macro. There may be a few of these.*/

int main()
{
    printf("foo = %d\n", foo); /*Prints 14. The value after the macro expansion */  

    printf("foo = %d\n", *backdoorfoo); /*Prints 10, via dereferencing the differently named pointer. */  

    return 0;
}
```

Note that using `#undef` is also a possible solution, but that is, in my opinion, only making things worse than they already are.

An alternative, if you cannot change the horrible code at all but are allowed to add a code file, is to exploit the fact that your `foo` is global.
It allows to access the actual global variable from a second code file, which does not contain the macro obstacle.

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo = 10; /*A variable at global scope. There may be a few of these.*/

#define foo (4 + foo) /*A self-referential macro. There may be a few of these.*/

void printfoo(void); /* only needed for demo */
int main()
{
    printf("foo = %d\n", foo); /*Prints 14. The value after the macro expansion */

    printfoo(); /* Only needed for demo. Prints 10, the value of global foo variable.  */

    return 0;
}
```

second.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern int foo;

void printfoo(void)
{
        printf("foo = %d\n", foo); /*Prints 14. The value after the macro expansion */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the sympathizing answer. The downvotes on the question is inexplicable.

Comment: I have downvoted the question because it lacks motivation (and prior research, e.g. reading  C reference documentation).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch:  The example code I had provided in the question was taken from the C reference documentation you have cited. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Self-Referential-Macros.html#Self-Referential-Macros. Would that have been possible without prior research?

Comment: But you forgot to cite it

Comment: My question was not about that specific example only, so I did not cite it in the question. Instead posting code from my work, I used what was available online. In any case, I cited that link in the comments section of the question.

Comment: I am trying to mediate here and to improve the question, not to take sides. Adding all information to the question itself, instead of in comments, is peferred. (I did that for you, assuming that you appreciate it.) It avoids being missed by readers. Doing that right away would also have prevented readers not seeing them **yet**. (I mention this because I think at least one of the downvotes is older than the corresponding comments.)

Comment: @Yunnosch: Thanks for improving the question as you see fit. I appreciate it. From now on, I will cite whenever needed in the question itself.